# PXSelect returns a POReceipt with a wrong VendorID

Tags: acumatica

This is inside an extension of a BLC (extending PXGraphExtension):

```cs
[PXOverride]
protected virtual IEnumerable resultRecords()
{
    foreach (PXResult<InventoryTranHistEnqResult, INTran> item in list)
    {
        PXResult<POReceipt> receiptResult = PXSelect<POReceipt, Where<POReceipt.receiptNbr, Equal<Required<POReceipt.receiptNbr>>>>.Select(Base, "999");
        POReceipt receipt = (POReceipt)receiptResult;
        PXTrace.WriteInformation(receipt.ReceiptNbr); // CORRECT
        PXTrace.WriteInformation(receipt.VendorID); // INCORRECT
    }
}
```

The Vendor ID of the receipt seems to be wrong, but the other details from the record seem to be correct? Here is the DAC for POReceipt. Do I need to do something to make the right Vendor ID get selected?

```cs
public partial class POReceipt : PX.Data.IBqlTable, PX.Data.EP.IAssign {
#region Selected

#region ReceiptType

#region ReceiptNbr

#region SiteID

public abstract class siteID : IBqlField { }
[IN.Site(DisplayName = "Warehouse")]
public int? SiteID
{
    get;
    set;
}
#endregion
#region VendorID

public abstract class vendorID : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
protected Int32? _VendorID;
[Vendor(typeof(Search<BAccountR.bAccountID,
    Where<BAccountR.type, 
        Equal<BAccountType.companyType>, 
    Or<Vendor.type, 
        NotEqual<BAccountType.employeeType>>>>), Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, CacheGlobal = true, Filterable = true)]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Vendor.status, IsNull, 
                        Or<Vendor.status, 
                            Equal<BAccount.status.active>, 
                        Or<Vendor.status, 
                            Equal<BAccount.status.oneTime>>>>), AP.Messages.VendorIsInStatus, typeof(Vendor.status))]
[PXDefault()]   
[PXFormula(typeof(Switch<Case<Where<POReceipt.receiptType, Equal<POReceiptType.transferreceipt>>, Selector<POReceipt.siteID, Selector<INSite.branchID, Branch.branchCD>>>, POReceipt.vendorID>))]
public virtual Int32? VendorID
{
    get
    {
        return this._VendorID;
    }
    set
    {
        this._VendorID = value;
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: How is the receipt wrong ? Is `receipt` null or did it return a different record than expected ? Are you sure your database contains a record with  999 as receiptNbr ?

Comment: please provide what output you are getting, and your PXSelect doesn't seems to be wrong.

Comment: Apologies, I thought I was getting the wrong receipt record but it seems to be right except one field is wrong (VendorID). The SQL statement seems to be correct. Do I need to do something for the DAC to get the right VendorID?

Comment: The second code snippet seems to be the original code for POReceipt, right ? If you didn't customize POReceipt, your code in the first snippet should work. What BLC did you do an extension of ?